# Inmobi Handling No Advt for this position

Tags: ads, inmobi

Sometimes when I try to load a new ad in InMobi I get a response like this:

[image]

There seems to be no corresponding callback for this. Please note the onError callback does not get called when this happens so I am unable to handle it in code.

Is there some other option to handle this case properly that I may have missed?

Comment: Hey Ram! I'm from the InMobi team. You are right when you say there's no corresponding callback. We are in the process of fixing this and it will be launched in a few days. Will keep you posted :)

Comment: @Sohan any updates on this problem?

Comment: Can you PM me your email ID, Ram ?

Comment: Hey Ram. This has been fixed now. Can you take a look?
Thanks for bringing this to our attention btw :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)